# Enable Archiving and Enable Editor Tracking on Oracle SDO

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, archiving

Are **enable archiving and enable editor tracking** allowed in Oracle database system (SDO)? Since I usually use PostgreSQL, I don't know the features supported by the Oracle database.

Comment: Enterprise geodatabase functionality is provided by ArcObjects, not RDBMS vendors. SDO_GEOMETRY is just a storage option.